# What are the non-trivial normal subgroups of $O(3)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

What are the non-trivial normal subgroups of $O(3)$? My guess is that the only one is $SO(3)$, but it's really only a guess, based on the fact that $O(3)$ is disconnected 3-manifold of $SO(3)$ and the set of reflective symmetries, which I'm not sure is even a subgroup (does it contain identity?)... I have no idea how to prove it.

So first I want to prove that $(\forall o \in O(3)) \space oSO(3) = SO(3)o$, then that there are no normal subgroups of $SO(3)$ and that the set of reflective symmetries is not a group.

(Please, be easy on me. I obviously don't know much about abstract algebra yet.)

Thanks!

Comment: Indeed the complement of $\text{SO}(3)$ is not a subgroup: it's not closed under multiplication and it doesn't contain the identity.

Comment: On the other hand, the group $SO(3)$ is simple as an abstract group. I think, Berger has a very nice geometric argument in his "Geometry" (first or second volume - I do not remember). Thus, $O(3)$ has only three normal subgroups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The orthogonal group $O(3)$ has a nontrivial subgroup consisting of the identity matrix and its negative. These lie in the center of $O(3)$, so the subgroup is normal.

To show that $SO(3)$ is normal, you might want to use the fact that $SO(3)$ is precisely the set of matrices in $O(3)$ with determinant $1$. This allows you to characterize cosets of $SO(3)$ in terms of determinants. After working this out, demonstrating that left and right cosets coincide will reduce to properties of the determinant.

Alternately, you could use this determinant fact to figure out the index $[O(3):SO(3)]$, and use this to conclude that $SO(3)$ is normal in $O(3)$.

**Edit:** As @QiaochuYuan points out, the most economical method would be to consider the determinant homomorphism, whose kernel is $SO(3)$.

Comment: You're doing too much work. $SO(3)$ is the kernel of the determinant, which is a group homomorphism, and the kernel of a group homomorphism is always a normal subgroup.

Comment: Ah, I see, so it is enough to realize that $(\forall S \in SO(3))(\forall O \in O(3))\space \det ( OSO^{-1} ) = 1 \implies OSO^{-1} \in SO(3)$, right? But it is not enough to show that $SO(3)$ is the only normal subgroup, because it can also contain other normal subgroups itself. Any advice on how to prove this is not the case, please?

Comment: Yes, that's one way to verify $SO(3)$ is a normal subgroup. As @studiosus mentioned in the comments, $SO(3)$ is simple: it contains no proper, non-trivial normal subgroups. Given this, what can you deduce about the intersection of any normal subgroup of $O(3)$ with $SO(3)$? (For a proof that $SO(3)$ is simple, you might look [here](http://chiasme.wordpress.com/2014/03/27/so3-is-a-simple-group-a-geometric-proof/) or refer to Berger's previously recommended book, "Geometry").