# Why $O(3)$ does not contain a normal subgroup $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: group-theory, manifolds

Why the orthogonal group $G=O(3)$ does not contain a normal subgroup, a cyclic group of order 2, $N=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$?

It looks that any $g \in G$ satisfies
$$
g N g^{-1}=N
$$
where  $N=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is generated by $-diagonal(1,1,1)$ of rank-3 matrix.

So why the orthogonal group $G=O(3)$ does not contain a normal subgroup $N=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, but only an $SO(3)$?

Comment: see also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881995/what-are-the-non-trivial-normal-subgroups-of-o3

Comment: Who said it doesn't? In fact $O(3) = SO(3) \times \{\pm I\}$. (And this works any any odd $n$, not just $3$.)

Comment: @amWhy, it is not duplicated, please read two questions to see difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are quite right that $N = \{ \pm I \}$ is a cyclic subgroup of order two that is normal in $O(3)$. In fact, it is the center of $O(3)$. We also have the internal direct product decomposition $O(3) = SO(3) \times \{ \pm I \}$, or more generally $O(n) = SO(n) \times \{ \pm I \}$ for any *odd* $n$.